# Is a contractive automorphism of a Banach algebra an isometry?

Tags: functional-analysis

If $A$ and $B$ are C*-algebras and $T:A\to B$ is an injective $^*$-homomorphism, then $T$ is necessarily isometric, that is
$\|T(a)\|=\|a\|$, for every $a$ in $A$.  In particular, every automorphism of $A$ is automatically isometric.

However this is not necessarily true for  Banach algebras: for a counter-example   one could take  $A$ to be any Banach space with
multiplication defined to be identically zero, that is $ab=0$, for every $a$ and $b$ in $A$, and then it is easy to
produce a contractive  automorphism of $A$ which is not isometric, e.g. $T(a) =a/2$.

In order to avoid such pathologies one could require $A$ to be unital and semi-simple.  The question would then be:

Let $A$ be a commutative semisimple Banach algebra with unit and $T$ be an automorphism of $A$ such that $\|Ta\| \leq \|a\|, a \in A$.
Is it true that $T$ is an isometry?

Comment: Is it true? Have you been told this? Why do you think it might / might not be? Etc. Posts should have detail

Comment: @geetha290krm,  your map is not an automorphism.

Comment: Arkady Kitover, I found your question quite interesting but it is under the threat of being closed due to some users considering it to lack context.  I therefore took the liberty of editing it, adding some context, hopefuly satisfying the people voting to close it.  I hope you don't mind!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I believe I've come up with a counter-example.  Consider $\ell ^\infty ({\mathbb Z})$ as a Banach algebra with coordinatewise
multiplication and norm
$$
  \|a\| = \sup_ic_i|a_i|,
  $$
where the $c_i$ are positive real numbers,  with $1<c_i<c_{i+1}$,  for every $i\in {\mathbb Z}$,  and
$$
  \lim_{i\to -\infty }c_i = 1, \quad\text{and}\quad   \lim_{i\to \infty }c_i = 2.
  $$
It is not hard to see that this is indeed  a sub-multiplicative norm due to the fact that the $c_i$ are bigger than
one.  Moreover, since the $c_i$ are bounded above and below, this norm is equivalent to the usual sup-norm on
$\ell ^\infty ({\mathbb Z})$,  hence a complete norm.   That $\ell ^\infty ({\mathbb Z})$ is semisimple is also clear, since it is isomorphic to a C$^*$-algebra.

The automorphism given by $T(a)_i = a_{i+1}$ is then contractive but its inverse,
$
  T^{-1}(a)_i = a_{i-1},
  $
isn't.

Comment: Nice example.+1